# how to copy message inside icmp header

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming

Here is the code which I don't quite understand.

```
struct icmphdr *icmp;
icmp = (struct icmphdr *)(sb->data + sb->nh.iph->ihl * 4);

....

char *cp_data = (char *)((char *)icmp + sizeof(struct icmphdr));
memcpy(cp_data, buffer, 4);
dev_queue_xmit(sb);
```

Basically what it does is copy the buffer to `cp_data`, which points to somewhere in `icmphdr` structure, but where does `cp_data` exactly points to? what is `(char *)((char *)icmp + sizeof(struct icmphdr))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cp_data, which points to somewhere in icmphdr structure

No, it does not, it points to the memory **after** the icmphdr.

That's where the ICMP payload is. Look at [this image](https://technet.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC196845.gif):

[image: ICMP structure]

The ICMP payload (message) starts after the header which has a size of `sizeof(struct icmphdr)` so it is located at `icmp + sizeof(struct icmphdr)`.

`memcpy(cp_data, buffer, 4);` therefore copies four bytes from `buffer` to the ICMP packet message.

`sb->data + sb->nh.iph->ihl * 4` actually skips the IP packet header and points to the ICMP header (look at the above image again). The IP header is at `sb->data`, the ICMP header at `sb->data + sb->nh.iph->ihl * 4` and the ICMP message at `sb->data + sb->nh.iph->ihl * 4 + sizeof(struct icmphdr)`.

For example, ping (echo request / reply) uses the ICMP message field to send the data forth and back. It can also be used for [ICMP tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_tunnel).

**Update:**

> if I want to get the size of data section, just do "size = 1500(MTU) - (sizeof(iphdr) + sizeof(icmphdr) + sizeof(ethhdr)). Is that correct?

No, not at all, for the following reasons:

1. MTU is just the maximal packet size that **can** be transmitted without fragmentation. ICMP packets should actually be smaller.
2. The MTU does not include the ethernet header, it defines the maximal packet length in layer 3 (IP, not ethernet!).
3. `sizeof(iphdr)` is incorrect because the header size can vary based on IP options. Use `iphdr.ihl` to get the size of the IP header **in 32 bit words**.

The correct way is to determine the total IP packet length and subtract IP header length and ICMP header length:

```
tot_len     = sb->nh.iph->tot_len
iphdr_len   = sb->nh.iph->ihl * 4
icmphdr_len = sizeof(icmphdr)
size        = tot_len - iphdr_len - icmphdr_len
```

**Note:** You should always use `ntohs` to convert *network byte order* to *host byte order*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explain! so cp_data points to the data section of a IP packet, if I want to get the size of data section, just do "size = 1500(MTU) - (sizeof(iphdr) + sizeof(icmphdr) + sizeof(ethhdr)). Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the explain. So is sk_buff represent the packet before fragmentation or after fragmentation? For example, struct sk_buff *sb; struct iphdr *ipheader = iphdr(sk); Is ipheader fragmented? Just confused about MTU(1500) and IP packet max size(65535).

Comment: @user2437651 Fragmentation happens at IP layer. Assuming `sk_buff *sb` refers to the received packet, the IP packet may be fragmented. I suggest reading the following articles: [IPv4 packet structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure), [IP fragmentation (overview)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation) and [IP fragmentation (explanation)](http://www.wildpackets.com/resources/compendium/tcp_ip/ip_fragmentation).

Answer (score 0):

1. In the code you pasted,

   `struct icmphdr *icmp; //is a pointer to the beginning of icmp header in a packet.`

& by this line- 
    `char *cp_data = (char *)((char *)icmp + sizeof(struct icmphdr));`

you make cp_data point to the beginning of the payload of the icmp packet.

2.`((char *)icmp + sizeof(struct icmphdr));`  - icmp is typecasted to (char*) so that the addition of (char*)icmp + sizeof(struct icmphdr) will return the address (icmpheader start address) + headersize bytes.

Here is an example - 
suppose you have an integer pointer and you increment it by one, it points to the next integer(that is it automatically advances 4 bytes ahead),while a character pointer advances by a single byte since a char is 1 byte.

And so, since memcpy is used to copy bytes from a buffer to where cp_data now points(the payload of the icmp packet), `(char*)icmp + sizeof(struct icmphdr)` is again typecasted to (char*).

Hope this helps!